# Localize a Blazor hosted Webassembly with a databse resource

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I try to localize my Blazor hosted Webassembly. For this i have created a Database and oriented on the following link:

https://www.ezzylearning.net/tutorial/asp-net-core-localization-from-database

But the tutorial is for a ASP.NET Core application. How can i use this solution in Blazor?

I following all the steps but in the end i can´t connect the database as a resource to my `IStringLocalizer<T> localizer`. How can i achieve that in my client project instead of the usual resx file the database is created via the controller in my server project is used?

Comment: In my opinion, it's impossible to localize  Blazor  Webassembly application with database, since this application is running at the client browser, there is no way to let all the client side Blazor application to connect to database.

Comment: @BrandoZhang meanwhile I think so too. I can not understand why this is a big deal, dynamically localization based on the database have been so much advantages and currently there is no possiblitiy? sad!

Comment: Yes, the normal way is store the localization related data into a json file or not and then render the page with the Json file according to the url's country information.

Comment: My goal was to change the resource data on runtime, with a resx file i wasn`t able to. Anyway, now i get the data from database. It is dirty but it works.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to implement your own version of the IStringLocalizer interface... however you should note that this is really just a shim interface over the ResourceManagerLocalizer, and the ResourceManagerStringLocalizerFactory.
These obviously use the ResourceManager which is where the resx file formats (which get embedded as resources into assemblies) come into it.

So you'd:

1. Create a DbStringLocalizer (implementing IStringLocalizer) which would retrieve your desired translation from the DB, you'd probably want to cache translations also, to avoid network round trips.
2. Create a DbStringLocalizerFactory which would cache DbStringLocalizer instances to avoid losing cached translations also
3. Create an Extension method to easily allow you to register your Singleton DbStringLocalizerFactory, and your Transient DbStringLocalizer

The .NET Core sources are readily available, so you could implement closely in line with the existing source.  Just using a DB connection (and CultureInfo handling) in place of the ResourceManager (which already handles CultureInfo lookups).

And the Microsoft guide for the ResourceManager Webassembly version (that you should use as your starting point for DB driven)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/globalization-localization?view=aspnetcore-6.0&pivots=webassembly