# How to implement .NET MAUI localization without RESX file

Tags: c#, localization, blazor-webassembly, maui

I would like to know how to implement localization on MAUI Hybrid App (or blazor WASM) without using RESX file. I need to call a web API to retrieve my translations in my database.

Do you have any exemples to make it?

Thanks

Comment: If you are getting the Strings from APIs why do you need localization at all? Just assign the correct strings and handle your current language yourself, This is one of the only cases where getting data from the API is actually the best solution..

Comment: It seems you can't localize the maui blazor appication from the database according to [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69457668/localize-a-blazor-hosted-webassembly-with-a-databse-resource).